# k-means clustering with new training data?

Tags: r, algorithm, data-mining

I'm working on some image recognition stuff and are trying to use k-means for matching algorithms.

Actually, I have lots of vectors (exactly speaking, SURF descriptors) on database and I would like to cluster them for future matching processes.

However, the problem is, I believe that the training dataset is going to grow (new training data may come), which make it impossible for me to train these data in one run.

It would be OK to cluster some data first, but does it mean that every new data need a full re-clustering? If I'm confident enough on existing clusters, does a minority of extra data (ex. 1% extra of all data) hurt the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-means is not a particularly smart algorithm. And on SIFT vectors, the results are often not much better than random convex partitions anyway.

If your initial sample was representative, there should be no need to rerun the clustering: the new data should have little effect on the centroids anyway.

To speed up the clustering, you can also re-use the previous centroids as initial seeds. This should require much less iterations then.

Comment: Actually just like what you have said in the last point, speed is essential. Regarding the representative thing, does that mean that if I would cluster great (representative) data in the first run, it would suit for not only 1% extra data, but 10x more? ... Or I still need a re-clustering every 2x~3x data growth?

Comment: K-means results are statistical averages. If your initial data is representative, how much do you think **means** would still change? (Well, k-means results are often really crappy, so rerunning it *may* yield entirely different results; but that doesn't mean they are better.)